# in spring boot app a rest api returns a response fields different from my response dto when an exception like 500 occurs

Tags: spring-boot, rest, response, exceptionhandler, uncaughtexceptionhandler

Getting this response but timestamp and path fields are not in my response `dto or exceptionHandler`.
the endpoint in the instances works correctly and returns the second response when deployed initially but some time later the first response starts to return in an unexpected way then after restart the problem is resolved. Why?

Likewise `Internal Server Error` is not involved codebase or in any bundle.

```
{
  "timestamp":"2023-07-18T11:30:06+03:00",
  "status":500,
  "error":"Internal Server Error",
  "message":"***",
  "path":"/rest/**/save"
}
```

expected response fields are below:

```
{
    "status": "FAIL",
    "message": "***",
    "errorCode": "**",
    "availableToRetry": false
}
```

Where does the response come from?

Debugged the exception Handler but it seems normal.

Comment: Looks like endpoint is not correct. Can you post Rest API url here.

Comment: it's correct. /rest/alternativeRec/save.
i debugged the request in the api method but it returns different fields from my response dto.

Comment: When you debug, what is the response in Service and Controller class?

Comment: it happens in some prod instances so i can't see this response in local env. 
in prod when second response expected first one comes out then i just restart the instances and the second response starts to come out as expected. 
So the endpoint in the instances works correctly when deployed initially but some time later the first response starts to return in an unexpected way then after restart the problem is resolved. Why?